# Express validation, custom async checking

Tags: node.js, express-validator

So, I have done a pretty good amount of research on this and I am having some issues.

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
const newUser = await usersDb();
// Define the user
const email = req.body.email;
const username = req.body.username;
const password = req.body.password;
const confirmPassword = req.body.confirmPassword;

// Start user already exist check
let userNameCheck = await newUser.findOne({ 'username': username});

req.check('email', 'Email is not valid.').isEmail()
  .custom(async value => {
    let emailCheck = await newUser.findOne({ 'email': value });
    console.log(emailCheck);
    console.log('Hmmm')
    if (emailCheck !== null) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }).withMessage('Email is already in use.');

//req.check('username', 'Username is required.').notEmpty();    
req.check('password', 'Password is required.').notEmpty();
req.check('confirmPassword', 'Confirm password is required.').notEmpty();

// Get errors
let errors = await req.validationErrors();
if (errors) {
   console.log(errors);
   res.render('index', {
    errors: errors
  });
} else {     
  console.log('Still bad');
}
});
```

I am having issues with the email check. It seems to be working for the most part but it is not returning an error. I know I am using the same email, and it is pulling it correctly. But the validation is not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15):

Okay this time I got it working, for real:

```
req.check('email', 'Email is not valid.').isEmail()
  .custom(async value => {
    let emailCheck = await newUser.findOne({ 'email': value });
    if (emailCheck !== null) {
      console.log('User Exists');
      return Promise.reject();
    }
}).withMessage('Email is already in use.');
```

And:

```
// Get errors
const errors = await req.getValidationResult();
console.log(errors.mapped())
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
   res.render('index', {
    errors: errors.mapped()
  });
} else {     
  console.log('Still bad');
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Yes, William your answer is completely correct I just wanted to add the reason why for any other curious minds.

If we use `asyncFunction` in custom validator we have to return a `Promise` object.
When validation works we don't need anything from the function hence works invalid cases, but `return false` will not work but `Promise.reject()` will.

Also, you can use `Promise.resolve()` to completely correct your code.

Comment: Thanks! You saved my time. I just used Promise.reject() instead of returning false in my custom validator.