# Using chain validation to check existence of optional fields with Express Validator

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I am trying to check for the existence of an optional field in an API request, and if that field exists, perform a nested validation to check if two other fields (one or the other, or implicitly both) exist inside of it.  I am using Express Validator to try and accomplish this task.

```js
// Sample request body
{
  <...>
  thresholds: {
    min: 3,
    max: 5
  }
}

// (Attempted) validation chain
check('thresholds').optional()
      .custom( innerBody => {
          console.log('THRESHOLDS', innerBody);
          oneOf([
              check('innerBody.min').optional(),
              check('innerBody.max').optional()
          ]);
      })
```

The above snippet is part of a larger validation chain I'm validating the full request body on.  I also tried removing the `innerBody.` string from the inner `check`s but still no luck.  I am `console.log`ing the threshold body, and it prints out correctly, however I still get a validation error, when I'm trying to get my integration test to pass:

```
{"name":"ValidationError","message":"ValidationError: Validation failed","errors":[{"location":"body","param":"thresholds","value":{"min":3,"max":5},"msg":"Invalid value"}]}
```

I am relatively new to Express Validator so if I'm chaining the validation wrong/not using `oneOf` correctly or something would love some pointers!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `.custom` function needs to return a `Promise`.  Answer below:

```
.custom(innerBody => {
            if (!(innerBody.min) || !(innerBody.max)) return Promise.reject('Missing min or max');
            return Promise.resolve();
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

> Remember: Always return a boolean value from the callback of .custom()
>   function. Otherwise your validation might not work as desired.

Source: [Custom validation guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-perform-custom-validation-in-your-express-js-app-432eb423510f/)

In general, you might have needs in use of *Promises* if you deal with asynchronous `.custom()` function. Then you'll be obligated to return `Promise.resolve()` / `Promise.reject()` for correct validator behaviour.

Source: [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57592019/9317057)